# fluentvalidation cascade stop fails to halt

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following :

```
internal sealed class LabelValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
   public LabelValidator()
   {    
        RuleFor(label => label)
           .NotNull()
           .NotEmpty()
           .MaximumLength(120);
    }
}
```

```
internal static class ValidatorExtensions
{
  public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MustHaveValidLabel<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
  {
     return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new LabelValidator());
  }
}
```

```
internal sealed class SharedFolderValidator : ResourceValidator<SharedFolderDto>
{
   public SharedFolderValidator(string labelPrefix, string groupPrefixFullControl, string groupPrefixReadOnly)
    {   
       RuleFor(resource => resource.Label)
           .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
           .MustHaveValidLabel()
           .Must(l => l.StartsWith(labelPrefix, StringComparison.Ordinal))               
    }
    
    protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<SharedFolderDto> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        base.PreValidate(context, result);
    
        [Some other tests]
    
        return !result.Errors.Any();
   }
}
```

```
public sealed class ValidatorBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : notnull
{
`    private async Task<TResponse> Validate(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        List<ValidationFailure> failures = _validators
            .Select(v => v.Validate(request))
            .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
            .Where(error => error != null)
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Any())
        {
            _logger.LogValidationResult(typeName, JsonSerializer.Serialize(request), failures);
            throw new ResourceDomainException();
        }

        return await next();
    }
}
```

`MustHaveValidLabel` is used on other usecases.

The code fails on `.Must(l => l.StartsWith(labelPrefix, StringComparison.Ordinal))` when `label` is empty / null but `CascadeMode.Stop` should have had stopped it.

**I'm not looking for workarounds.**

I'd like to understand why `CascadeMode.Stop` won't work in that usecase.

I added PipelineBehavior and static class for the extension.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my attempts to reproduce - your validator is not executed at all (not sure why though, maybe `string` is a special type for fluent validation). One workaround is to change the validator to be a `PropertyValidator<T, string>`:

```
internal sealed class LabelValidator<T> : PropertyValidator<T, string>
{
    public LabelValidator()
    {    
    }

    public override bool IsValid(ValidationContext<T> context, string value)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length <= 120;
    }

    protected override string GetDefaultMessageTemplate(string errorCode) => "label is not valid"; // TODO
    public override string Name => "Label validator";
}

internal static class exts
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MustHaveValidLabel<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new LabelValidator<T>());
    }
}
```

Or move the the rules to the extension method:

```
internal static class exts
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MustHaveValidLabel<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.NotNull()
            .NotEmpty()
            .MaximumLength(120);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your workaround but I'm more interested on the 'why' it fails as it is.

Comment: @Vincent - because the validator is not invoked  =)

Comment: lol yeah... but why :P

Comment: @Vincent it seems that by design - see [github issue](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/184)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was elsewhere and linked to the `PreValidate`. I thought the problem was down to `FluentValidation` but it was not.

The validation code is common to validate part of of the model in an API and dtos further down the app.

The API is using `AddFluentValidationAutoValidation()` ( https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore#aspnet-core-integration-for-fluentvalidation)

I was missing a test of null / empty / white space in the PreValidate of the base class.

The model to dto validation was failing because of that.

---

Edit:

AddFluentValidationAutoValidation is obsolete (not async)
A lot easier to validate manually